# Button return to page where I come - with referrer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a function where returne to page where I come (*previously*)

**This is my code**

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Назад" onclick="myFunction()" class="btn" />
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.referrer;
    document.getElementById(".btn").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Where I'm Wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
function myFunction() {
  window.location = document.referrer;
}
```

You can also use:

```
function myFunction() {
  window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: Where use window.history.back(); ?

Comment: @Gohyu Inside the `myFunction` instead of `window.location = ...` statement.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want within a function:

```
function myFunction() {
    window.location = document.referrer;
}
```

However, you're doing this a little overcomplicated, as this is a typical case where inline JS is a good choice (because it's little code that's specific to this element, and therefore easier to maintain than having to look it up in a seperate script file).
You're also using a submit element where you probably shouldn't (as it's meant to be used to submit a form, which you don't have).

Instead, you can use either a regular link:

```
<a href="' + document.referrer + '">Назад</a>
```

or a button element (this has the advantage of rendering identical to the submit element in most browsers, plus you likely won't need the `btn` class because you can directly address the element):

```
<input type="button" value="Назад" onclick="window.location = document.referrer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This script returns you to the previous page when called.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.referrer;
    window.location = x;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Cleanup your answer.